# Best way to store multiple controls in an array

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a UserControl in WPF with numerous child controls which I would like to index like an array. These child controls are in the same grid control as other child controls which I am not interested in.

I'd like to be able to index these controls in a way similar to:

```
someControl.Children[3];
```

With out having to avoid controls which I am not interested in. Here's a sample of what I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="gCalendar">
    // more crap here...

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">Blah</TextBlock>


    <Internal:DayCalendarTime Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" />
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Internal:DayCalendarCore Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7"/>
</Grid>
```

I would like to have an array consisting of just the Internal:DayTimeCore controls by putting some sort of wrapping control around them.

Is this possible, or will I manually have to make the array by looping through all children of the grid and adding the ones that are of the type I am interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another non-WPF way,
  Create a code behind control collection by

```
foreach(DayCalendarTime control in gCalendar.Children)
{ 
  controlCollection[i++] = control;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap these controls inside another Grid control

Comment: There's nothing more light weight?